# Docker-compose with Storm 0.10.0 and Zookeeper (connection loss)

Tags: node.js, docker, apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

having the following architecture deployed:

1. Apache Kafka and Zookeeper inside a docker container: https://hub.docker.com/r/eucm/kzk/
2. Storm (Nimbus, Supervisor, UI) using these images:

   - https://hub.docker.com/r/eucm/storm-nimbus/
   - https://hub.docker.com/r/eucm/storm-ui/
   - https://hub.docker.com/r/eucm/storm-supervisor/

Using the following 'docker-compose.yml'

```
# A scalable cache
#     saves data to ./data/mongo
mongo:
    image: mongo:3.0
    container_name: "mongo"
    volumes:
      - "./data/mongo:/data/db"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

# Kafka (A scalable queue) + Zookeeper (Distributed conf. service)
# as of 2015.11 -- kafka:0.8.2.1, zookeeper:3.4.5+dfsg-2
kzk:
    image: eucm/kzk
    container_name: "kzk"
    volumes:
      - "./data/zookeeper:/var/lib/zookeeper"
      - "./data/kafka:/tmp/kafka-logs"
    environment:
      - ADVERTISED_HOST=localhost
      - AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS=true
      - DELETE_TOPICS=true
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "2181:2181"

# nimbus: supervises everything; talks to zookeeper
# in e-ucm/dockerized-storm -- storm:0.10.0
#    requires: kzk
nimbus:
    image: eucm/storm-nimbus
    container_name: "nimbus"
    environment:
      - KZK_PORT_2181_TCP_ADDR=kzk
      - NIMBUS_PORT_6627_TCP_ADDR=nimbus
      - UI_PORT_8081_TCP_ADDR=ui
    ports:
      - "6627:6627"

# ui: allows access to logs
# in e-ucm/dockerized-storm -- storm:0.10.0
#    requires: nimbus, kzk
ui:
    image: eucm/storm-ui
    container_name: "ui"
    environment:
      - KZK_PORT_2181_TCP_ADDR=kzk
      - NIMBUS_PORT_6627_TCP_ADDR=nimbus
      - UI_PORT_8081_TCP_ADDR=ui
    ports: 
        - "8081:8081"

# supervisor: supervises actual workers
# in e-ucm/dockerized-storm -- storm:0.10.0
#   requires: nimbus, kzk, mongo
supervisor:
    image: eucm/storm-supervisor
    container_name: "supervisor"
    environment:
      - KZK_PORT_2181_TCP_ADDR=kzk
      - NIMBUS_PORT_6627_TCP_ADDR=nimbus
      - UI_PORT_8081_TCP_ADDR=ui
    ports:
      - "6700:6700"
      - "6701:6701"
      - "6702:6702"
      - "6703:6703"
```

We also use NodeJS and kafka-node package (https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node) to create a topic called 'sessionTest'.

And I send this topology (https://github.com/e-ucm/rage-analytics-realtime/blob/master/src/main/java/es/eucm/gleaner/realtime/RealTime.java) to Storm from the host machine. Using the following command:

```
/home/dan/storm-test/storm/apache-storm-0.10.0/bin/storm jar /home/dan/storm-test/realtime-jar-with-dependencies.jar es.eucm.gleaner.realtime.RealTime sessionTest mongodb://localhost:27017/analytics-backend-test localhost:2181 -c nimbus.host=localhost
```

After a while, watching the Storm workers logs (inside the supervisor image) we see the following error.

```
2016-03-30 09:30:05.984 b.s.d.worker [INFO] Shutting down worker sessionTest-3-1459329789 2c94d927-2341-4649-bee6-b0bb13f2706f 6700
2016-03-30 09:30:05.985 b.s.d.worker [INFO] Shutting down receive thread
2016-03-30 09:30:06.006 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] creating Netty Client, connecting to supervisor:6700, bufferSize: 5242880
2016-03-30 09:30:06.009 b.s.m.loader [INFO] Shutting down receiving-thread: [sessionTest-3-1459329789, 6700]
2016-03-30 09:30:06.009 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] closing Netty Client Netty-Client-supervisor/172.20.0.5:6700
2016-03-30 09:30:06.009 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] waiting up to 600000 ms to send 0 pending messages to Netty-Client-supervisor/172.20.0.5:6700
2016-03-30 09:30:06.009 b.s.m.loader [INFO] Waiting for receiving-thread:[sessionTest-3-1459329789, 6700] to die
2016-03-30 09:30:06.010 b.s.m.loader [INFO] Shutdown receiving-thread: [sessionTest-3-1459329789, 6700]
2016-03-30 09:30:06.010 b.s.d.worker [INFO] Shut down receive thread
2016-03-30 09:30:06.010 b.s.d.worker [INFO] Terminating messaging context
2016-03-30 09:30:06.010 b.s.d.worker [INFO] Shutting down executors
2016-03-30 09:30:06.011 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Shutting down executor $spoutcoord-spout0:[2 2]
2016-03-30 09:30:06.011 b.s.util [INFO] Async loop interrupted!
2016-03-30 09:30:06.789 b.s.util [ERROR] Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/topics/sessionTest/partitions
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:81) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.trident.ZkBrokerReader.<init>(ZkBrokerReader.java:42) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.makeBrokerReader(KafkaUtils.java:57) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.trident.Coordinator.<init>(Coordinator.java:33) ~[stormjar.jar:?]http://e-ucm.github.io/a2/#api-Login-Login
    at storm.kafka.trident.OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout.getCoordinator(OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout.java:46) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.trident.spout.OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor$Coordinator.<init>(OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor.java:44) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.trident.spout.OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor.getCoordinator(OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor.java:183) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.trident.topology.MasterBatchCoordinator.open(MasterBatchCoordinator.java:113) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5624$fn__5639.invoke(executor.clj:564) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:477) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_45-internal]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/topics/sessionTest/partitions
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:94) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:65) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/topics/sessionTest/partitions
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1590) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:214) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:203) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:199) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:191) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:38) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:91) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:65) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    ... 11 more
2016-03-30 09:30:06.794 b.s.d.executor [ERROR] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/topics/sessionTest/partitions
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:81) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.trident.ZkBrokerReader.<init>(ZkBrokerReader.java:42) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.makeBrokerReader(KafkaUtils.java:57) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.trident.Coordinator.<init>(Coordinator.java:33) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.trident.OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout.getCoordinator(OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout.java:46) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.trident.spout.OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor$Coordinator.<init>(OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor.java:44) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.trident.spout.OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor.getCoordinator(OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor.java:183) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.trident.topology.MasterBatchCoordinator.open(MasterBatchCoordinator.java:113) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5624$fn__5639.invoke(executor.clj:564) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:477) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_45-internal]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/topics/sessionTest/partitions
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:94) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:65) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /brokers/topics/sessionTest/partitions
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1590) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:214) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:203) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:199) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:191) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:38) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getNumPartitions(DynamicBrokersReader.java:91) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:65) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
    ... 11 more
2016-03-30 09:30:06.805 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
    at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:336) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__7188$fn__7189.invoke(worker.clj:536) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__5523$fn__5524.invoke(executor.clj:261) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:489) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_45-internal]
```

I have already confirmed that I can send data to the kafka docker image and consume them correctly (through a console consummer).

TLDR: Deployed Kafka, Zookeeper, Storm as docker images. Sent data to kafka from the host machine, and storm workers (that should consume from kafka) show connection loss logs with zookeeper.

Any idea would be useful, thanx!

Comment: Could be caused by resource constraints. I had similar ZK issues when we deployed several images on a low spec box. How many cores do you have available?

Comment: Found the problem. There was a problem with the Kafka Advertised Host property being setup wrong. (kafka configuration)

Comment: @DanCristianRotaru could you please explain how did you exactly resolved it? We are facing similar issue while connecting Kafka 0.10x using Storm 0.10x version. The same code is running fine with lower kafka (0.9x) version. Really appreciate if you could provide an answer